# MQTT Android Paho Library not connecting to my localhost broker

Tags: android, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to make a simple Hello World style program for the android device and test my MQTT broker running on my localhost. This is what I have done so far:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String broker = "tcp://192.168.X.X:1883";
    String clientID = "AndroidClient";
    final MqttAndroidClient mqttClient = new MqttAndroidClient(MainActivity.this, broker, clientID);

    try {
        mqttClient.connect();
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(mqttClient.isConnected()){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not connect to the server!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }

    //Do more things...
}
```

Everytime I run the code, it runs the else block. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I have Mosquitto running and the localhost address is what's displayed in my ipconfig, so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

All Help Is Appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413643/paho-mqttandroidclient-connect-always-fails

Comment: Please update the question with the logcat output from the time of the failure so we can see any error messages

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the doc for the [MQTTAndroidClient](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/android-javadoc/index.html?org/eclipse/paho/android/service/MqttAndroidClient.html) it says it's is an implementation of the [IMqttAsyncClient](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/index.html?org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/IMqttAsyncClient.html), meaning methods will return immediately and continue in the background,

This means that the client is unlikely to have completed connecting by the time you call `mqttClient.connect();`

Given you are running this code in on create (where you should not really run blocking tasks) you should look at using the `onSuccess` callback to detect when the connection has completed e.g.:

```
IMqttToken conToken;
conToken = asyncClient.connect("some context",new new MqttAsyncActionListener() {
  public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
    log("Connected");
  }

  public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
    log ("connect failed" +exception);
  }
});
```